# Java Asynchronous servlet is still blocking application

Tags: java, tomcat, servlets, jakarta-ee

Here is my code:

```
@WebServlet(value = "/path", asyncSupported = true)
public class Path extends HttpServlet {
private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

/**
 * @see HttpServlet#HttpServlet()
 */
public Path() {
    super();
    // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
}

/**
 * @see HttpServlet#doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
 */
protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    request.setAttribute("org.apache.catalina.ASYNC_SUPPORTED", true);

    AsyncContext ac = request.startAsync();
    Runnable r = new Runnable() {

        @Override
        public void run() {
            try {
                Thread.sleep(10000);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            try {


                ac.getResponse().getWriter().append("Served at: ").append(request.getContextPath());
                ac.complete();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    };
    new Thread(r).start();



}
```

When I run this twice back to back, the second time waits for the first one to complete before it starts, taking 10 seconds longer instead of running async and completing right after the first one. How do I fix this?

Comment: *When I run this twice back to back*: what are you doing, precisely? Even if you don't use asynchronous requests, the server will process the two requests concurrently.

Comment: https://www.javacodegeeks.com/2012/05/servletrequest-startasync-limited.html

Comment: @JBNizet Like if I run it twice in my browser back to back. The second one will take 10 seconds on top of the first one finishing instead of finishing 1 second after

Comment: That's not precise. Explain precisely what you're doing, what you expect to happen and why, and what happens instead. Example: "I open a Firefox window and a Chrome window. I enter the address in the Firefox location bar and hit enter. Then I immediately do the same in the Chrome window. I expect both windows to display "Server at" after 10 seconds (Chrome slightly after Firefox due to the small delay between the moments I hit enter), and instead, Chrome displays "Hello world" after 2 seconds, and Firefox does nothing for 2 minutes, and then plays a rolling stones song"

Comment: @JBNizet I open a chrome window, open two tabs, put in my URL in both, press enter on the first one, and one second later press enter on the second one. Instead of the first one completing and displaying a result in 10 seconds and the second one completing 1 second after, the second one completes 10 seconds after the first one

Comment: Now we're talking. I have no definitive idea of why you get that, but here's what I would do to find out. 1. Use two different browsers, to see if it's a browser issue. 2. Test with a normal, synchronous request, to see if it's used by your usage of an async request. 3. Read the documentation of your server to see what the effect of this request attribute is, how it works, etc.

Comment: @JBNizet Two different browsers worked. Why would that be though?

Comment: Because Chrome probably decides that it shouldn't send two concurrent requests to the same URL, either because the response of the first could be cached, and it would thus save one request, or because it doesn't want to spam a server resource.

Comment: @JBNizet Makes sense. Thanks!